# How to convert a Turing Machine program to a tiling using Wang Tiles?

Tags: computer-science, tiling

To illustrate my question I provide the following example.

The website [Online Turing Machine](http://db.ing.puc.cl/turingmachine/) provides a Turing Machine simulator. The following program adds 1 to any binary number.

q0,1 
q0,1,>

q0,0 
q0,0,>

q0,_ 
q1,_,<

q1,0 
q3,1,>

q1,1 
q1,0,<

q1,_ 
q3,1,>

A program line has the following format 
state, character read 
new state, character written, direction tape

In the program above q0 is the initial state and q3 is the accepting state.

In Tilings and Patterns by Gruenbaum and Shephard, 11.4 "Computing By Tiles" I read that it is possible to convert any turing machine program to a tiling of the plane using Wang tiles. The book contains an example tiling which calculates the Fibonacci numbers. The procedure, recipe, to convert a Turing machine program to a set of Wang tiles is not entirely clear to me.

**Question: What is the algorithm to convert a Turing Machine program line by line to a set of tiling of the plane using Wang Tiles?** And how does it work on the Turing machine in the given example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the policy on posting pictures in answers, but I recently wrote up how to do this as part of a proof of the undecidability of the Wang (domino) tiling problem. It would take considerable time to translate into tex and diagrams, so here goes:

(They may need to be viewed in full size to get some of the details)

**Edit**: It's somewhat difficult to describe well how this exactly emulates a TM, but this should allow you to construct a tileset from a simple machine, then you can understand how the process works by actually playing with an example.

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]

Comment: An answer after all, thanks G.H. Faust, will study this.